# Outlook 2007 - Intercepting a mail delete command

Tags: vba, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I'd like to send delete mails to a user created folder rather than the deleted items folder.

Is there a way to intercept a mail that I have either deleted from within the message, or deleted from a folder/inbox and send it to that user defined folder instead?

I thought I could write a script to watch the deleted items folder for mail, and then moving it over to the user defined folder, but then i would never actually be able to delete anything correctly as it would keep moving it back. Whereas if I could intercept it after a click of the delete button I always have the option to 'move' the message into the deleted items folder if I really do want to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a custom [`UserProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862196.aspx) on your `Item` *(Mail, Task, Calendar, etc.*) so that once it's been placed in the user-defined `DeletedItems` folder it could be permanently deleted.

The the logic that moves it do the user-defined `DeletedItems` can then check for the user property existence...

```cs
 if (mailItem.UserProperties["SoftDelete"] != null)
   // keep in REAL deleted items
 else
 {
   // move to user-defined deleted items
   mailItem.UserProperties.Add("SoftDelete", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo, false, false).Value = true;
   mailItem.Save(); // persist user props
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would see what the VBA would look like for this. It isn't pretty but it works.

```
Private WithEvents olDeletedItems As items
Private WithEvents olToBeDeletedItems As items

Private Sub Application_Startup ()

Dim objNS As NameSpace
Dim Cancel As Boolean

Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olDeletedItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).items
Debug.Print "Adding items to the - Deleted Items - folder will trigger olDeletedItems_ItemAdd"

Set olToBeDeletedItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("To be deleted").items
Debug.Print "Adding items to the - To be deleted - folder will trigger    olToBeDeletedItems_ItemAdd"

End Sub

Private Sub olDeletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

Dim myNameSpace As NameSpace
Dim targetFolder As MAPIFolder

On Error GoTo notYes ' There is an error when there is nothing in SoftDelete

Debug.Print item.Subject & " - " & item.UserProperties("SoftDelete").Value
If item.UserProperties("SoftDelete").Value <> "Yes" Then

    GoTo notYes
Else

    'The item has already been soft deleted
    ' Okay to remain in the real deleted folder

End If

On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

notYes:
Debug.Print item.Subject & " - Either not a Yes or there is nothing in SoftDelete"

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set targetFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("@To be deleted")

item.Move targetFolder

Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set targetFolder = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub olToBeDeletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

item.UserProperties.Add("SoftDelete", olText).Value = "Yes"
item.Save

End Sub
```